# MySQL foreign key constraints through more tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I find myself stack to this problem. I've got the following 3 tables, which I can't modify (it'd be so nice):

Person

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| SSN        | varchar(50) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name       | varchar(50) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |       |
| birthday   | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Employee

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| SSN        | varchar(50) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| department | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| salary     | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Employer

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name       | varchar(50) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| department | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| salary     | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Contract

```
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| employer_name  | varchar(50) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| employee_name  | varchar(50) | YES  | PRI | NULL    |       |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I know that:

- employee(sin) is foreign key to person(sin),
- employer(name) is foreign key to person(name),
- contract(employer_name) is a foreign key to employer(name)

And I should insert another foreign key for contract(employee_name), though employee table has only the SSN. Is there a way to reference the foreign key to person.name, passing through employee table, something like

```
CONSTRAINTS FOREIGN KEY contract(employee_name) REFERENCES TO person(name) WHERE person(sin)=employee(sin);
```

? 
Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: This is not how foreign keys work.  And you seem to be very confused, linking a name to an SSN.

Comment: Not the one who created the db, I've been given this and I've to "work" with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An SQL FK constraint says its referencing column list subrow values, if all non-NULL, have to appear as subrow values for its referenced column list, which must be declared UNIQUE/PK in a base table.

Your constraint is not an SQL FK constraint.

If we could use a query in the place of the referenced base table name in an SQL FK constraint then the constraint you would want would be:

```
Contract(person_name) REFERENCES
    (SELECT name FROM Person p JOIN Employee e ON p.name = e.name)(name)
```

(It can be shown that `name` is `UNIQUE` in that table.) But we can't.

If MySQL supported `CREATE ASSERTION` then you could `CHECK` that every `Contract person_name` was `IN (SELECT name FROM Person p JOIN Employee e ON p.name = e.name)`. But it doesn't.

So this is an example of a constraint that, if you can't redesign your tables, you would enforce by appropriate triggers when the tables involved change.

> Is there a way to reference the foreign key to person.name, passing through employee table, something like

If you want to figure out situations like this then you have to forego the cop-outs of using precise terms like "foreign key" just because you are *somehow reminded* of the things they refer to but that *aren't there*, or using the poetic "passing through", or using the vague "something like". You have to actually write out the conditions that you want your tables to satisfy.